# How to create relationships between elements in react loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

**I wish to create a list of links, all revealing their individual thumbnail image on hover.** Neither the links nor the thumbnails are static – I am querying them from an external source using graphql. Now obviously what I have attempted won't work as the links don't have any relationship to their thumbnails, and I'm selecting all of them at once.

How do I create relationships between the images and links when mapping through my data? Or is this the wrong approach entirely? Will this even work with Gatsby, a static site generator?

```js
import React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql, Link } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

const LinkTree = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query queryPosts {
        allContentfulPost {
          edges {
            node {
              slug
              dateOfCompletion(formatString: "YYYY MM")
              title
              thumbnail {
                sizes(maxWidth: 1280) {
                  ...GatsbyContentfulSizes
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )

  const post = data.allContentfulPost.edges

  return(
    <ul>
      {post.map((post, i) => (
        <li key={i}>
          <Link to={post.node.slug}>
            {post.node.dateOfCompletion}
            {post.node.title}
          </Link>

          <Img
            sizes={post.node.thumbnail.sizes}
          />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

export default LinkTree
```

Comment: You may bind those, storing them as an object properties within array of all such link-thumbnail pairs. If you would post the sample of your source data, I would suggest some relevant code.

Comment: Could you please create a running sample on https://codepen.io/

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I've added the rest of the code, including the graphql query

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own custom code to create a popup which will be visible on hover/onMouseEnter and you can get the target link, set the image url in state like `visibleThumbnail` and then show that image in popup and then on onMouseLeave, hide the popup (using some flag) and reset the `visibleThumbnail` to empty or it does not matter since it is not visible.

There is very useful package called `rc-trigger` that you can use to show a popup on different actions like on click, hover, contextmenu etc.

Here is demo page

http://react-component.github.io/trigger/examples/point.html

Here is api
http://react-component.github.io/trigger/

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Trigger from 'rc-trigger';
import 'rc-trigger/assets/index.css';

const builtinPlacements = {
  topLeft: {
    points: ['tl', 'tl'],
  },
};

class Test extends React.Component {
  state = {
    action: 'click',
    mouseEnterDelay: 0,
    visibleThumbnail: ''
  }

  setVisibleThumbnail = (e) => {
     const thumbnail = someLogicToGetTheTheumbnail();
     this.setState({ visibleThumbnail: thumbnail  });
  }

  render() {
    const { mouseEnterDelay, visibleThumbnail } = this.state;

    return (
<ul>
  {post.map((post, i) => (
    <li key={i}>
  
<Trigger
            popupPlacement="topLeft"
            action={['hover]}
            popupAlign={{
              overflow: {
                adjustX: 1,
                adjustY: 1,
              },
            }}
            mouseEnterDelay={mouseEnterDelay}
            popupClassName="point-popup"
            builtinPlacements={builtinPlacements}
            popup={<div
    
  >
    <img src={visibleThumbnail} />
  </div>}
            alignPoint
          >
       <Link id={post.node.id} onMouseEnter={this.setVisibleThumbnail } onMouseLeave={this.hideThumbnail}>
        {post.node.dateOfCompletion}
        {post.node.title}
       </Link>
      </Trigger>

      <Img
        className="thumbnail"
        sizes={post.node.thumbnail.sizes}
        alt={post.node.slug}
        style={style}
      />
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
    );
  }
}
```